# jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

The javascript console in Google Chrome complains that
   `$("#zipInput").removeAttr('required');​​​​​`
contains an
    Invalid or unexpected token

I include jQuery at the top of the html file and can verify that elsewhere in the file it seems to be working fine. What is the problem with this particular line?

```
<form method='post' >
    <input id="zipInput" type="text"name='zip' placeholder='zipcode' autofocus required>
    <input id="SSNInput" type="text"name='ssn' placeholder='ssn' required> <br>     
    <input type="submit" class='center' value="Log In">
    <input id='newCustomer' type="submit" name="newCustomer" value="New Customer?">
</form>     

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newCustomer").on("click", function(e) {
            $("#zipInput").removeAttr('required');​​​​​
            $("#SSNInput").removeAttr('required');​​​​​
            return true;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you cut/paste that code from somewhere else?  It's probably an invisible Unicode character like a zero-width space or something. Try retyping the code by hand.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. Invisible characters at the ends of *both* `removeAttr` lines.

Comment: AHA! I did copy *those* lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird encoded characters after both `$.removeAttr();` lines. Try copying/pasting this, or using a simple text editor that will show the hidden encoded characters.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newCustomer").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#zipInput").removeAttr('required');
        $("#SSNInput").removeAttr('required');
        return true;
    })
});
```

Comment: yeah, there were some weird characters

Comment: Thank you!!  I'm so glad I asked (: